# NullPointerException starting on notification

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, notifications

I have made a media player. Now, I want to put one XML file in my notification area. For this, I followed this flow but I got a `NullPointerException` when starting the notification.

**1.** Add service in Android manifest file

```
service class=".MDService"
android:process=":remote"
android:name=".MDService"
```

**2.** Create `MDSInterface.aidl` as follows

```
interface MDSInterface {        
    void start();
    void stop(); 
}
```

**3.** Made a `MDService` class for remote view and in that, I add an XML file and add in a notification area. Following is the code

```
package org.streamingmusic.main;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.DeadObjectException; 
import android.os.IBinder; 
import android.os.RemoteException; 
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MDService extends Service
{

    public static NotificationManager nm;   
    private static final int  NOTIFY_ID = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nm =(NotificationManager)
        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        nm.cancel(NOTIFY_ID);
    }

    /**
    * Set notification on play song
    * @param Trackname
    * @param  Artistname
    */
    public void startnot() {
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "SMS", 0);
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.mindback);

        notification.contentView = contentView;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StreamingPlayer.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notification.contentIntent=contentIntent;
        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }

    public IBinder getBinder() {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public final MDSInterface.Stub mBinder = new MDSInterface.Stub() {
        public void stop() throws RemoteException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            nm.cancel(NOTIFY_ID);
        }

        public void start() throws RemoteException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startnot();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

**4.** Declare object of `MDService` class in player activity

```
public static MDSInterface mpInterface;
```

**5.** Bind a service

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(
                getApplicationContext(), MDService.class),
                mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

**6.** Add a service connection method

```
public static ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mpInterface = MDSInterface.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)service);
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mpInterface = null;
    }
};
```

Please, can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Actually, my goal is to give a functionality in the notification area so that the user can play the next or previous song, pause the song, and also go to the application.
This means adding four buttons in the notification area. If anybody has a better way, then please share. I appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. It's straight-forward. You can copy it into SO, highlight it and press CTRL-K. The way it is now, it's unreadable.

Comment: You need to re-do the formatting of the post -- it's unreadable.  Paste your code again but use the curly-brace button to format it, not the quote icon.

Comment: I just spent a hell of a time editing this post.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly without bothering to read your code, this kind of thing usually results from trying to call a method of a null object returned from a previous call.

Moral of the story is always to check that returned objects are non-null before calling their methods!

If they are null, you need to figure out and resolve the error with the object retrieval call.